# I don't know where to begin web development for a project I'd like to work on

Tags: web-deployment-project

I'd like to make a website that documents the programs and courses at my school as well as allow you to search through the information and select courses from results. I have a clear vision of what I'd like it to look like but I'm not sure what I need to learn to accomplish the goal.

I want to hook it up to a database and have those results shown in rows with various columns of information. I'd want the table to have alternating background colours, something I'd imagine was easy, but I'd want there to be no borders and have the ability to select and highlight a row. Kind of that having a bunch of joined cells in excel make up rows if data with tabs between information and the ability to highlight rows and select them with a mouse or use the arrow keys.

To be honest, this is very out of my element but I'd like to try learning through attempting this project. I'm just unsure what I would need to use to do something like this.

edit: good point. My experience. Some machine code, python and java, nothing too complex, mostly just school assignments and whatnot. Currently starting a course where I'll be learning some C and another one on database management and manipulation.

Comment: I know I can be a bit wordy, but I meant to ask which tools or languages I should look at for working on the kind of project I was describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention your programming experience level or preferred languages, but I suggest [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/) with the sqlite back-end as probably the easiest way to prototype what you want.  It's super simple to set up a basic project in Django, and I find the documentation to be top-notch.  The Admin application also will allow you to manage your app data easily.  If you're not too particular, the Admin app might suffice for your entire interface.  If your database is preexisting and accessible to you, you don't need sqlite, just use [this information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/legacy-databases/).

Once you get the basic backend working (the Django tutorial alone might even get you that far), [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) may be the easiest way to style your site the way you want.  Getting the spreadsheet interface just like you want it may not be super practical.  It's much easier to have a list screen just for displaying all of your data and details screens for editing individual items.  But if you're dead set on a spreadsheet interface, maybe [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-django/index.html) would help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it tomorrow morning as I'm just about to head to bed but it looks very interesting. I'm not particularly attached to the spreadsheet interface but it seems to best articulate what I meant. I also added in my experience at the top, it's my first question so I didn't even think to include it.

Comment: If you already know python, you'll be in really good shape with Django.  It's designed to keep the nitty gritty database stuff pretty well abstracted from you, so as long as you're pretty good with OOP, you shouldn't have too much trouble.  I have a feeling you'll find the Django Admin app to be a revelation :)